# MpAndroidChart - CombinedChart with several LineChart and one BarChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using CombinedChart from MpAndroidChart to construct a chart that can have several line and one bar (like this image).

[image]

However, the CombinedChart just draw **one** LineChart.

```
List<LineData> myLines = populateMyLines();
CombinedData dataChart = new CombinedData(values);

for(LineData line: myLines) {
      dataChart.setData(line);
}
dataChart.setData(new BarData(barValues));
chart.setData(dataChart);
```

Comment: Are you sure your other datasets contain data? Have you cross-checked your code with the combined-chart code from the example project?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda I add  data.setData(generateLineData2()); (that has different values) to the example code from the library project, and it's drawing just one line

Comment: @PhilippJahoda it's adding the correct labels (Line DataSet, Bar dataset, and linedata set 2). But just draw the last line.
And before I set the chart data, I have 2 LineData and 1 BarChar into my combinedData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WORKAROUND:**

```
 LineData linesData = new LineData();
   for(LineData dataSet: dataSets) {
        linesData.addDataSet(dataSet.getDataSetByIndex(0));
   }
 dataChart.setData(linesData);
 dataChart.setData(generateBarData());
```

---

Please see below for the sample code modified from the CombinedChart example ,

```
public class CombinedChartActivity extends DemoBase implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

    private CombinedChart mChart;
    private final int itemcount = 12;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_combined);

        mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);

        // draw bars behind lines
        mChart.setDrawOrder(new DrawOrder[]{
                DrawOrder.BAR, DrawOrder.LINE
        });
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);

        CombinedData data = new CombinedData(mMonths);
        // data.setData(generateCandleData());

        LineData mlineData=generateLineData();
        mlineData.addDataSet(generateLineData1().getDataSetByIndex(0));

        data.setData(mlineData);





        data.setData(generateBarData());
//        data.setData(generateBubbleData());
//         data.setData(generateScatterData());
//         data.setData(generateCandleData());

        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();
    }

    private LineData generateLineData() {

        LineData d = new LineData();

        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
            entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(50, 40), index));

        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line DataSet");
        set.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        set.setLineWidth(3.5f);
        set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setCircleSize(5f);
        // set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setDrawCubic(true);
        set.setDrawValues(true);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setHighLightColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }

    private LineData generateLineData1() {

        LineData d = new LineData();

        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (int index = 3; index < itemcount; index++)
            entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(10, 40), index));

        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Line DataSet");
        set.setColor(Color.RED);
        set.setLineWidth(3.5f);
        set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setCircleSize(5f);
        // set.setFillColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setDrawCubic(true);
        set.setDrawValues(true);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 238, 70));
        set.setHighLightColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }



    private BarData generateBarData() {

        BarData d = new BarData();

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
            entries.add(new BarEntry(getRandom(15, 30), index));

        BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "Bar DataSet");
        set.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        return d;
    }

    protected ScatterData generateScatterData() {

        ScatterData d = new ScatterData();

        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
            entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(20, 15), index));

        ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(entries, "Scatter DataSet");
        set.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        set.setScatterShapeSize(7.5f);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }

    protected CandleData generateCandleData() {

        CandleData d = new CandleData();

        ArrayList<CandleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<CandleEntry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++)
            entries.add(new CandleEntry(index, 20f, 10f, 13f, 17f));

        CandleDataSet set = new CandleDataSet(entries, "Candle DataSet");
        set.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
        set.setBodySpace(0.3f);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }

    protected BubbleData generateBubbleData() {

        BubbleData bd = new BubbleData();

        ArrayList<BubbleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BubbleEntry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
            float rnd = getRandom(20, 30);
            entries.add(new BubbleEntry(index, rnd, rnd));
        }

        BubbleDataSet set = new BubbleDataSet(entries, "Bubble DataSet");
        set.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        set.setHighlightCircleWidth(1.5f);
        set.setDrawValues(true);
        bd.addDataSet(set);

        return bd;
    }

    private float getRandom(float range, float startsfrom) {
        return (float) (Math.random() * range) + startsfrom;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.combined, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionToggleLineValues: {
                for (DataSet<?> set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
                    if (set instanceof LineDataSet)
                        set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
                }

                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionToggleBarValues: {
                for (DataSet<?> set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
                    if (set instanceof BarDataSet)
                        set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
                }

                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {




    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the workaround @TSG. This is an issue already created in the lib https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1216

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could perhaps  try with single linedata and add  different line datasets as when needed . I was hit with the same issues when I try with two different linedata ie. linedata1 with SetA,linedata2 with SetB until   I got it resolved with single linedata having two or more datasets.

```
CombinedData data = new CombinedData(Xvals);
       // data.setData(generateCandleData());
 LineData d = new LineData();
d.addDataSet(setA);
d.addDataSet(setB)
        data.setData(LineData());
        data.setData(BarData());
```

Combinedchart currently is governed by one single XVal set ,please be careful to code the correct XVal index reference in the Xval ,YVal Entry pair

Comment: ?. So, you are populating the dataSet 'd'. And then you do nothing with the d dataset??

Comment: Not exactly , the above code snippet is just for  reference only , both the data Set A & B are having line entries , the xval index are somehow different , first Xvals for  Set  A may be started off at 10 while  Set B Xval entries can be of any variables . The X coordinate is rather restricted at the moment , only single set is allowed , this is instantiate during the combined chart creation.

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant , this reference should be d.addDataSet(setA);
d.addDataSet(setB)
        data.setData(d);  just add the  LineData with two different set of entries and follow by BarData 
        data.setData(BarData()); this should resulted in having two line objects shown on the combined chart